# How to access to calling and manage call's

Tags: android

I am contemplate about managing calls in my app. There is a posibility to call sb and disconnect after let say 1 minute? I want to make sth like "economical caller" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

search about

-BroadcastReceiver

-Android AlarmManager

-And type google:

*android how to call a number

*android receive incoming/outgoing call

BUT you must searh before getting help.